# Possible to get typeof generic type parameter?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am writing a simple de/serializer that works for any type of `State`. Is there any way to get the concrete types of a generic type parameter? Code sample is shown below.

```js
type ValType = number | boolean;

interface State {
    [index: string]: ValType;
}

function serialize(x: ValType): string {
    if (typeof x === 'number') {
      return `n${x}`;
    } else {
        return `b${x}`;
    }
}

// return dummy values instead of reading from string
function deserialize(x: string, type: string): ValType {
    if (type === 'number') {
      return 0;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function serializeState<T extends State>(s: T): string {
    let ret = '';
    
    Object.values(s).forEach(v => {
        ret += serialize(v);
    })

    return ret;
}

function deserializeState<T extends State>(s: string): T {
    // ???? how to get keys and value types from T ???? <--------------------------
    
    // e.g., ['number', 'boolean']
    const types = [];
    // e.g., ['counter', 'isDone']
    const keys = [];

    // deserialize based on actual types
    T ret;
    for (let i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
        ret[keys[i]] = deserialize(s, types[i]);
    }

    return ret;
}

interface StateA extends State {
    counter: number;
    isDone: boolean;
}

const s: StateA = { counter: 1, isDone: false };
const str = serializeState(s);

console.log(deserializeState<StateA>(str));
// expected: { counter: 1, isDone: false };
```

Comment: TypeScript's static type system, including generic type parameters, is [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) from the emitted JavaScript.  So there is no `T` or `State` or `StateA` at runtime to use.  The right way to solve problems like this is generally to come up with exactly how you want it to happen at runtime in JavaScript, and then annotate/describe that JavaScript code with static types to make it into TypeScript.  Instead of passing `StateA` to `deserializeState`, you'll need to pass some actual JS value that represents it.

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/lWYKrN) maybe?  If it meets your needs I'll write it up as an answer.  If not, please elaborate on what the issue is.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, it works like a charm. How to make StateA conform to State interface since my state must be a non-nested string-keyed record? Also, how to use the serialize/deserialize in Javascript? I am exporting it as a library to be used in both ts & js.